# Showing realtime HEADING in ArcMap using GPS positioning toolbar?

Tags: arcmap, gps, heading

How can I display a real-time GPS position in ArcMap 10.1 using the GPS toolbar?

We have it setup so position works fine. Just ArcMap refuses to interpret HEADING. So the real-time icon cannot rotate according to it.I checked ESRI documentation regarding real-time GPS of course.

Funny detail: None of the screenshots used by ESRI itself show a heading value in the window explanations. Always just 0.0 (which is at least more than the N/A I got). So maybe heading is an always buggy function anyways that just never got addressed?

I'll describe our setup briefly and add some screenshots for clarification.

We're on a vessel, doing offshore exploration. We use dive robots for this (ROVs). They get tracked pretty precise by underwater sonar vessel systems and their positioning is handled by a specific software (in our case: Fugro's Winfrog 3.1).

Being able to display the ROV in realtime in a **"rich data context"** as ArcMap allows, is important for us. So Winfrog now outputs a NMEA compatible string to ArcMap i.e. ESRI documentation says it is required format over network virtual **COM132**.

The string is indeed detected fine by ArcMap and  position, date and time come in fine, just HEADING does not. I attached screenshots of the Winfrog string config, the string setup in ArcMap and the position window in ArcMap, showing **N/A** for heading.

Regarding the various Winfrog config options: I'm very sure we tried all variations for the position string etc. in the past, currently cannot verify since I do not have access to the live system.

The string as configured by Winfrog comes in in sets of 3 rows like also shown on an attached screenshot (captured with Hyperterminal). I show two of such blocks. Small edits for this forum include masking of real lats/lons and the dashed line as visual separators for the string "blocks".

In real, string has numeric lat/longs and no dashed lines of course. Further find a version of that string naming the string elements instead of values, at least how I understand it.

String

[image: string]

Winfrog settings (string config)

[image: Winfrog settings]

ArcMap incoming connection

[image: ArcMap connection setup]

ArcMap position window, heading "N/A"

[image: ArcMap GPS Position window, LAT/LON blurred]

Comment: ArcGIS 10.1 has been in Retired support status for a while now. It seems likely something was changed in the terminal releases of 10.2.2, 10.3.1, 10.4.1, 10.5.1, or 10.6.1.

Comment: Thanks Vince, just tested it with ArcMap 10.4 installed on my private laptop - same thing: pos, date, time OK, heading N/A.

Comment: If you wish to ask about ArcGIS Desktop 10.4 then you should mention that in your question

Comment: No, I wished to ask about 10.1, which is the version installed on the working PC. And I did. Vince mentioned, 10.4 might have fixed my issue. I tested this on my private PC and found that the issue is the same. So my problem remains and 10.1 is the version it's about.

Comment: No one ever had a GPS heading in realtime being displayed in ArcMap and can tell me how he/she did it? Or what I do wrong?